# Double for loops in React using .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to create a double for loop in React for some JSON content that I created:

```
"students": [
        {
          "name": "person",
          "photoURL": "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100",
          "subjects":[
            "physics",
            "math",
            "english"
          ],
          "nextClass": "August 29th, 2018"
        },
        {
          "name": "human",
          "photoURL": "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100",
          "subjects":[
            "chemistry",
            "math",
            "french"
          ],
          "nextClass": "August 27th, 2018"
        }]
```

In my JSX, I'm trying to loop through the student objects and then loop through all the subjects again to make an unordered list:

```
render(){

    return(
          <div id="display-students">
            {this.props.students.map((x,i) =>{
              return (
                <div className="student" key={i}>
                  <h2>{x.name}</h2>
                  <img src={x.photoURL} alt="profile"/>
                  <h3>Subjects: </h3>
                  <ul>
                      {x.subjects.map((y) => <li>{y}</li>)}
                  </ul>
                </div>  
              )
            })} 
          </div>
        )
   }
```

However, this error shows up in the browser:

[image]

When I try and render out

```
<ul>
    {x.subjects}
</ul>
```

I see the content in the array all mashed up into one string:
[image]

Any pointers on why this is happening? 
Can we even use double for loops in JSX?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Double-loops are fine. I've taken your exact code and data set and was able to render a `ul` just fine. Is this the entire dataset?

Comment: If your content is all mashed up in one string that is probably because you haven't parsed the JSON data.  Where exactly is the string at? Is X a string? if it is you should do JSON.parse(x), HOWEVER it shouldn't be a string in the first place, so whatever is providing you with the prop is giving you an array of strings rather than an array of JSON objects

Comment: @Joao Pretty much, except for the fact that there is one more student object in the array- I'm mocking the back-end for now and using `res.send(*json here*)`

Comment: @kyle I doesn't look like it's a string - on the inverse, when I used `JSON.stringify(*array*)` it returned a stringified version of the array like so,
```"subjects":["physics","math","english"]```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is worthy of an answer, because it seems like the solution could be in your api. But I think @kyle might be on to something. Although, if you want to return json, I usually use `res.json(jsonDataHere)` when using `express` in the backend. My first thought was: maybe some of those students don't have any subjects (`subjects` doesn't exist). But secondly, you could debug it by using `console.log(typeof x.subjects)`

Comment: @Joao I tried using `res.json(jsonDataHere)` as well but ran into the same issue..

Comment: I checked the type of `{x.students}` and it returned `object`, so I know for sure it isn't a string

Comment: Without more info, I'm out of ideas, especially since your examples here work perfectly fine. I'm guessing this has something to do with how you're mocking your api response, and likely not a problem with the component itself.

Comment: I mean @Joao may be right as well and he brought up a great point, does every student definitely have subjects defined? and if they don't have any is it at least an empty array?

Comment: @Joao thanks for your patience so far - I'm using a `class component` and the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to run an async action to fetch data from the back-end and update the store. Could any of these things be causing an issue?

Comment: @kyle yes, each element has a subjects array for sure - Since I'm mocking the api, it only has 3 students each having a subjects array with 3 subjects in it

Comment: I used `Array.isArray(x.students)` to confirm it's an array.. This is strange if it's only happening on my local-env

Comment: What if you recreate the double-loop in your `fetchAllStudentsAsync` function before you `dispatch`? So just make a double loop that logs to the console. Does the error happen there? Just to verify that the react app isn't modifying the data as it comes in?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I found the error! It was because I was making an async call and the store wasn't updating before the first render, so `x.subjects` was `undefined` on first render. 
I fixed this by adding a conditional that checks if the value if undefined and returns a `loading` message.

Thank you so much for your help, you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same logic. It works perfectly fine in the below compiler.

```js
let students = [
        {
          "name": "person",
          "photoURL": "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100",
          "subjects":[
            "physics",
            "math",
            "english"
          ],
          "nextClass": "August 29th, 2018"
        },
        {
          "name": "human",
          "photoURL": "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100",
          "subjects":[
            "chemistry",
            "math",
            "french"
          ],
          "nextClass": "August 27th, 2018"
        }]
        
const Component = (props) => {

    return(
          <div id="display-students">
            {props.students.map((x,i) =>{
              return (
                <div className="student" key={i}>
                  <h2>{x.name}</h2>
                  <img src={x.photoURL} alt="profile"/>
                  <h3>Subjects: </h3>
                  <ul>
                      {x.subjects.map((y) => <li>{y}</li>)}
                  </ul>
                </div>  
              )
            })} 
          </div>
        )
   }
   
   ReactDOM.render(<Component students={students} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! 
I guess the issue wasn't as much as a `.map` issue as much as failing to fully understand my life-cycle methods.

`x.subjects` is an array, however it's undefined on first-render because the response from the back-end hasn't been received by the front-end yet.

To fix this, I managed to do something like this:

```
<ul>
   {x.subjects === undefined ? "loading..." : x.subjects.map((y, j) => <li key={j}>{y}</li>)}
</ul>
```

This allowed for the first render to avoid failing.

This spun me off on another tangent wondering if this is the right way to load initial state. Right now I'm:

- dispatching an action in an async call (using redux thunk) in the component
- This updates the store and passes data down into the props
- Once it does that, the component re-renders, displaying the data it received from the back-end

I wonder if there's a better way to do this...

Comment: You can set the props in a state. Then On a constructor you can initialize 

      stateName : []

from there you can see that it would never be undefined , it would be an empty array by default